# Debounce on a onclick function using typescript react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, debouncing

I am trying to implement lodash debounce function on an onclick function to avoid multiple clicks on a button. The solution I came up with is as follows:

```
function saveForm() {
//do stuff here
}

<Button onClick={debounce(() => saveForm, 1500, {
              maxWait: 2000 })}>
              SAVE
</Button>
```

I have seen many examples where debounce is performed on a function outside the return and then just use that debounced function under onclick. Is performing debounce directly (inline) on the button element wrong practice ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as good coding practice is concerned, you should avoid putting too much of business logic inside JSX. Just extract your `onClick` handler outside JSX.

Secondly, You do not want to return `saveForm` after debounce. Rather call it. So replace `() => saveForm` with `saveForm`.

```
function saveForm() {
//do stuff here
}

const debouncedClickHandler = debounce(saveForm, 1500, {maxWait: 2000})

<Button onClick={debouncedClickHandler}>SAVE</Button>
```

You can also use `useCallback` hook. I leave it up to you to explore the best practices for using `useCallback` hook if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

If your component is re-rendered frequently, I think it could be replaced to `useCallback`, but in normal case, I think your usecase looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you can you can add a loading state and based on that loading state disable the button.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we will validate within the form and save form outside the component. That gives clear valid input data and blindly save.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, @abdemirza right - better solution from UX perspective of view - it's to add loading state and disable button, when you async function do something.

It's not a mistake to use a debounce, but better use loading state